# Interactive plots on local .html via .rmd or Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, knitr, plotly

I'm trying to build a .html file via RStudio in to have following function(simplified).

**plot1**:a simple time series plot of $y_t$, where user can manually pull/drag each dot to change it's values a each time point.

**plot2**:a time series dependent on $y_t$, such as $f(y_t)=2*y_t+1$, once the value in plot1 changed, the plot2 will also change accordingly.

I want the .html self contained, not cloud based. I'm thinking of plotly, shininy/knitr, but I'm not sure if I'm in the direction or how to connect the dots. Hope anyone can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

A self-contained/client-side html report sounds well-suited for [flexdashboard](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/index.html).  It's based on [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/), and therefore can accommodate Shiny elements.

I don't know if you can modify values with a mouse, but you can certainly modify values with [sliders](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/sliders.html) and [other inputs](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/update-input-demo.html), as well as [have a second plot react to a first plot](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-zoom.html).

You may see some more possibilities in the [gallery](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I checked the gallery and didn't find what I'm looking for. I want to change/move the points in the graph instead of just change the parameter of the plot framework (e.g. ymin, ymax)

Comment: @xappppp, if you're looking to modify `x-axis`, `highcharter` offers some [examples](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highstock.html#time-series)

Comment: or  framing axis like [this](https://gallery.shinyapps.io/093-plot-interaction-basic/) or [scatterD3](https://data.nozav.org/app/scatterD3/)